# Comparison of two lists in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, comparison, mask

I have two lists in Haskell.

Original List: **["hello", "HELLO", "world", "WORLD"]**

Only Upper Case List: **["HELLO", "WORLD"]**

Could you help me to create a function which should return a list conatining the indexes of intersection of two lists.

I can get the first index by doing this:

**let upperIndex = findIndices(==(onlyUpper !! 0)) original**

However, this only works for one instance, in this case I can only get index of "HELLO" in the original list, but I want to get all of them.

For this example, the answer should be: **[1,3]**

Comment: You are very close. Think about what kind of predicate you will want to give `findIndices` though. If we have `upperIndex = findIndices (\x -> _) original`, what kind of a condition should you replace `_` with? What should it mean if that condition is true?

Comment: I am a beginner and honestly do not know :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**: Another version suggested by David Young is

```
findIndicesIn xs ys = findIndices (`elem` ys) xs
```

which I prefer to my solution below.

---

If I understand correctly, you have two lists. Call them `xs` and `ys`. You want to find the index in `xs` of each element in `ys`. You don't mention what you want to do if the element in `ys` is not contained in `xs`, so I am going to choose something reasonable for you. Here it is:

```
findIndicesIn :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [Maybe Int]
findIndicesIn xs ys = map (`elemIndex` xs) ys
```

`elemIndex :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Maybe Int` finds the index of the given element in the list (comparing with `(==)`). If the element does not exist, `Nothing` is returned instead. To find all the indices, we map over each element in `ys` and try to find it in `xs` using `elemIndex`. Section syntax is used instead of `flip elemIndex xs` or `\y -> elemIndex y xs` for concision.

The result is a list of `Maybe Int` representing the *possible* indices in `xs` of each element in `ys`. Note that if you do not keep track of missing elements, the positions of the indices in the resulting list will no longer correspond to the positions of the elements in `ys`.

You can also write this using fewer points as

```
findIndicesIn :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [Maybe Int]
findIndicesIn xs = map (`elemIndex` xs)
```

YMMV on which one is more clear. Both are equivalent. This version is pretty readable IMO. You can go one step further and write

```
findIndicesIn = map . flip elemIndex
```

but personally I find this less readable. YMMV again.

Comment: So, why do I get "just 1" , "just 3" instead of 1 and 3?

Comment: I have found that it was another data type, so I converted it to Int using "map fromJust xs". Thank you for the answer, it works perfectly too and a lot shorter!!!

Comment: @Orkun Don't do that. It will cause your program to crash if an element isn't found in the first list. You get `Just 1` and `Just 3` because there's no guarantee that elements in the second list will be found in an arbitrary list and `Maybe` handles that possible failure.

Comment: Because the second list is derived from the first one. To be specific, I get the upper case string elements from the original list. So there is no possiblity it will not found the the second list.

Comment: You can avoid the `Maybe` values in the first place by continuing to use `findIndices`.

Comment: @DavidYoung But then you get `[Int]` instead of `Maybe Int`. The original specification wasn't clear, so I had to take some liberties when interpreting it. `[Maybe Int]` seemed like the closest thing to the desired `[Int]` that handled failures in a reasonable way.

Comment: @Orkun If you have some guarantee that the indices will always exist then it is appropriate to use `fromJust`, but keep in mind that this imposes upon you the obligation to prove that there won't be any missing values. The compiler can no longer prevent you from making that mistake.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs The question gives a specific result of `[1,3]` for the sample input, which seems, to me at least, to lead in the direction of `findIndices`.

Comment: This works just fine but can you tell me how it can be done with findIndices? Because it was logical to use. However I do not understand how index increment happens in loop in this language, I cannot initialize an index and iterate over it...

Comment: @DavidYoung mapping over `findIndices` would give `[[1],[3]]`.

Comment: @DavidYoung Damn, you're right, I read `findIndices` wrong. That would be better.

Comment: No it works too and "[elem](http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/elem_f.html)" definition says : returns True if the list contains an item equal to the first argument. How can a boolean value can be used as an index?

Comment: @Orkun `(\`elem\` ys)` is the predicate used by `findIndices` to determine whether an index is found. Make sure you read the docs for `findIndices`.

Comment: So far we found the indexes right. Let's say I want to print those indexes from original list. If i say `print (original !! (\`elem\` upperIndex))` this should work right?

Answer (score -3):

```
let upperIndex original onlyUpper = helper original 0 where helper [] _ = []; helper (x:xs) i = if elem x onlyUpper then i:(helper xs (i+1)) else helper xs (i+1)
```

Example of use:

```
Prelude> upperIndex ["hello", "HELLO", "world", "WORLD"] ["HELLO", "WORLD"]
[1,3]
```

Comment: Works flawless thank you :) I do not understand why people gave minus. Sorry about that :(

Comment: This answer should have an explanation of why and how it works.

Comment: Oh, I see. But he put effort for me I appreciate it. Thank you again Sir.